# What species of viper is this?

Tags: species-identification

I think that the snake in the pictures here below is a viper. I found it on a hiking trail on a mountain in Bulgaria. Height was about 2000 meters and the weather wasn't warm as you might expect in a late Spring days, but it seemed quite active.

If it really is a viper what species of viper? Otherwise what could it be?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely the common European adder (*[Vipera beris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vipera_berus)*). A list of the [reptiles of Bulgaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_reptiles_of_Bulgaria) lists it as occurring in the mountains of Bulgaria up to 2700 metres.

There are a couple of other contenders in the list of vipers, but two of them are incredibly rare (not found since the 1930's) and the last is the horned viper (*[Vipera ammodytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vipera_ammodytes)*), which has distinctive horns on the tip of its nose.

Comment: Thank you. The description of the common adder is a good match and it had no horns, although it was quite young I think the second option can be discarded.